# How does Phineas put his shirt on?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

Some people might say that the characters in *Phineas and Ferb* only look strange to viewers, but that in-universe they look "normal" to each other. However, the series has shown that the characters are actually aware of their strange body shapes and a lot of other things too.

Sometimes they will comment on Phineas' lack of a chin or his triangular head. The same thing also can be applied to any other character in the show. Sometimes characters look so different from each other that it looks like they belong to different universes.

So, my question is, how does Phineas put his shirt on? Is his shirt that stretchy? If that were the case, wouldn't it wear off eventually, anyway? I know that both brothers have a lot of the same clothes to change, but I think that is too simple an explanation.

Comment: Why would that be too simple of an explanation? Also I’m not too sure you need two whole paragraphs of build up here to get to your question though I won’t edit it out.

Comment: My head is bigger than my neck, but I still manage to put on a shirt most mornings.

Comment: @MikeHarris - Your co-workers have asked me to ask you to make that *every morning*

Comment: @Valorum Whoops, I had hoped no one noticed.

Comment: How does Arnold Shortman put his shirt on? Stewie Griffin?

Comment: @BCLC Stewie doesn’t put his shirt on. His mom puts it on him. :-P

Comment: I thought my answer was nicely comprehensive. Let me know if there's anything else you'd want before considering an acceptance

Answer (score 158):

[image]

Images courtesy of [Phineas and Ferb the Movie: Across the 2nd Dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phineas_and_Ferb_the_Movie:_Across_the_2nd_Dimension)

Comment: Like all of us, his nose is made of squishy cartilage.

Comment: The difference is that fabric appears to be a lot stretchier in cartoon world than in the real world.

Comment: That fabric comes from the same place as the outfits for the characters: Elongated Man (aka Randolph "Ralph" Dibny) on Flash, Mister Fantastic (aka Reed Richards) on Fantastic Four, Elastigirl (aka Helen Parr or Mrs. Incredible) on The Incredibles.

Comment: @Rafalon they built a portal to Mars, that's hardly the weirdest way they violated the laws of nature that morning ;)

Comment: In that animation, his sleeves should not get coloured on the side away from the brushes, but some how they are.

Comment: @Kami The shirt must be textured in such a way that capillary action pulls the color in.

Comment: @Kami what are supposed to think? That it's some kind of magic xylophone?

Comment: @Kami I did comment something along those lines, which was upvoted 33 times yesterday, but for some reason my comment just disappeared. (by the way, I would love to know what happened to my comment)

Comment: Is a picture is worth a thousand words, how many is a short animated image worth?

Comment: @jpmc26 - As my old teacher used to say, "*a movie is a coordinated synthesis of performance, composition, sound, and editing that creates meaning"*

Comment: How much do you want to bet that the stripes were added that way because the animators didn't want to animate Phineas putting on a striped shirt?

Comment: Is that body painting??